# docker connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Tags: networking, docker, debian

I am trying to update my apt repos inside docker container but I cannot do that.

docker run -it --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 debian apt-get update

...

Cannot initiate the connection to httpredir.debian.org:80 (2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2001:41c8:1000:21::21:35 80]

...

docker run -it --dns 8.8.8.8 --dns 8.8.4.4 debian apt-get -o Acquire::ForceIPv4=true update

...

W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/jessie/updates/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to security.debian.org:http: [IP: 212.211.132.32 80]

...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Docker build has no network, but docker run has](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763418/docker-build-has-no-network-but-docker-run-has)

Answer (score 1):

maybe refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763418/docker-build-has-no-network-but-docker-run-has/38068368#38068368) ?

Like I answered there my container had no outside world network connectivity (so no DNS, etc.) where the docker host still had. thus the 'apt-get' was doomed to fail ...
Restarting the whole machine (only the a restart of the docker.service didn't solve it(?)) sorted the issue. Possibly some other dependency (I suspect the firewalld) had corrupted the docker networking ???

I wonder how to *"reset"* the docker networking to a clean state ? I'll have to investigate this ...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was solved after I ran the following two commands:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```