docker dotnet restore error:error mounting "/docker/containers/./resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": possibly malicious path detected
I am building a .Net 6.0 program in Docker. The project structure is as follows:
MyProject
├── XXXX.Repository
├── XXXX.WebApi
├────── Dockerfile
└── XXXX.sln
My Dockerfile content is as follows:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY *.sln ./
COPY ["XXXX.WebApi/", "./XXXX.WebApi/"]
COPY ["XXXX.Repository/", "./XXXX.Repository/"]


WORKDIR "/src/XXXX.WebApi"
RUN dotnet restore 

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 7777 

COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "XXXX.WebApi.dll"]

My compile command:
cd /MyProject
docker build  -f XXXX.WebApi/Dockerfile -t myapi-img .

When I build the image, the following error occurs:
Step 1/15 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
 ---> 27ce95112d34
Step 2/15 : WORKDIR /src
 ---> 8acb24c3cfe5
Step 3/15 : COPY *.sln ./
 ---> 933adbefb54e
Step 4/15 : COPY ["XXXX.WebApi/", "./XXXX.WebApi/"]
 ---> 18020079fca0
Step 5/15 : COPY ["XXXX.Repository/", "./XXXX.Repository/"]
 ---> 77480c8f6cdd
Step 6/15 : RUN dotnet restore
 ---> Running in b50c2706738c
OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error mounting "/data/docker/containers/b50c2706738cff21e132f815d7fb94ea884f5fb51895b64510012c33666854ab/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": possibly malicious path detected -- refusing to operate on /etc/resolv.conf: unknown

I have been googling stackoverflow for a long time, but I still can't find a solution.Someone suggested that I adjust /etc/docker/daemon.json as follows:
{
    "registry-mirrors": [
      "https://docker.unsee.tech",
      "https://dockerpull.org",
      "https://docker.1panel.live",
      "https://dockerhub.icu"
    ],
    "dns": [
      "172.28.130.123",
      "100.125.108.250",
      "8.8.8.8",
      "114.114.114.114"
    ]
  }

I also adjusted /etc/resolv.conf:
# Generated by NetworkManager
search openstacklocal novalocal
nameserver 172.28.130.123
nameserver 100.125.108.250
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 114.114.114.114

but the error still occurred.If I don't use docker, everything is normal.
docker Version: 19.03.4
system version: Centos 7.2

I update docker to 26.1.4.  error continue:  error mounting "/data/docker/buildkit/executor/resolv.conf" to rootfs at "/etc/resolv.conf": possibly malicious path detected -- refusing to operate on /etc/resolv.conf

Maybe you should check whether your build has network access at all. (E.g. try running curl to an external address as part of the build). This question may be relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31763418/docker-build-has-no-network-but-docker-run-has
